# Git push in parallel processes failing

Tags: bash, git

I have automated bash jobs making git changes and pushing them to origin. They are all editing the same file, but always different lines in that file so there will never be a conflict. Each job looks something like:

```
git clone
make change to file
git pull
git add .
git commit -a -m "message"
git push
```

The git pull was added to minimize the possibility that a parallel job can make changes and push after current job has made a clone, but hasn't pushed its changes yet. This works most of the time, but sometimes still a parallel job will be able to push a change after current job has pulled changes, but hasn't committed yet. This results in current job getting a error saying that I don't have the latest changes locally.

Is it possible to write a "try pull until push is successful" bash command or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git push` should return a non-zero status to the shell if it fails, so you can use a simple `while` loop in your bash script:

```
while ! git push; do git pull; done
```

If there is some other error, this will produce an infinite loop, so you might want to add a counter to abort after a certain number of attempts.

You probably also want to avoid lots of automatic merge commits being created by multiple pulls, so should use the `--rebase` option for `git pull`, which will re-create your new commit linearly after existing commits instead.

Putting that all together, you might end up with something like this (untested, please point any bugs you find):

```
success=0;
attempts=0;
until $success || [ $attempts = 10 ];
do
    let ++attempts;
    git pull --rebase;
    git push;
    success=$?;
done;
if ! $success;
then
    echo "Gave up after $attempts attempts";
fi
```